# Excel: Adding a row disrupts formula

Tags: excel, formula

In a spreadsheet I use for cash management tracking, I have the following formula:
=IF(D176="Cash", F175+C176, IF(D176="Transfer", F175+C176, F175))

When I add a row, I use control+D to fill in the formula from the cell above (I'm using Excel for Mac 2011). This results in the correct formula as follows:
=IF(D177="Cash", F176+C177, IF(D177="Transfer", F176+C177, F176))

However, this has the effect of changing the formula in the cell in the row below:
=IF(D178="Cash", F176+C178, IF(D178="Transfer", F176+C178, F176))

Here you can see the rows for column F are not correct: F176 should be F177.

Can anyone offer any advice to ensure that when I insert a row the formula remains intact?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you inserting rows below all of your existing data or in between existing rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace all of the references to F175 in the original formula (the one if row 176) with `INDEX(F:F, ROW()-1)`.

```
=IF(D176="Cash", INDEX(F:F, ROW()-1)+C176, IF(D176="Transfer", INDEX(F:F, ROW()-1)+C176, INDEX(F:F, ROW()-1)))
'or better as
=INDEX(F:F, ROW()-1)+(OR(D176={"Cash", "Transfer"}*C176)
```

Comment: Using the INDEX function in the first example you gave seems to be working beautifully.

The second option didn't seem to work for me, and I'm not sure what to do to make it work. Not that it really matters for my problem—just interested really.

Thank you!

NickPeranzi: I was attempting to insert rows between other rows, not at the end of the data column.